PostGreSQL 12 : Logical Replication - Specific Schemas
I've two database servers : Host 1 & Host 2
On the Host 1, I've several schemas in the database :

SchemaA
SchemaB
SchemaC
etc...

I would like ste in place a logical replication from Host 1 to Host 2 for only Schema A and Schema B
I've modified the postgresql.conf on the Host 1
*############# REPLICATION #############
listen_addresses = '*'
max_worker_processes = 8                # (change requires restart)
wal_level = logical                     # minimal, replica, or logical
synchronous_commit = on                 # synchronization level;
max_wal_senders = 10                # max number of walsender processes
synchronous_standby_names = '*'     # standby servers that provide sync rep
max_logical_replication_workers = 4     # taken from max_worker_processes
max_sync_workers_per_subscription = 2   # taken from max_logical_replication_workers*
I've created the user/role replica_usr on  Host 1 & Host 2
I've modified the pg_hba.conf on each host :
host    replication     replica_usr     X.X.X.X/28        md5
host    replication     replica_usr     Y.Y.Y.Y/28      md5
I've created the publication on Host 1
CREATE PUBLICATION schemaA_publication;
I've add the table of the schema :
ALTER PUBLICATION SchemaA_publication ADD TABLE "SchemaA"."Table1";
ALTER PUBLICATION SchemaA_publication ADD TABLE "SchemaA"."Table2";
etc...
CREATE PUBLICATION schemaB_publication;
I've add the table of the schema :
ALTER PUBLICATION SchemaA_publication ADD TABLE "SchemaB"."Table1";
ALTER PUBLICATION SchemaA_publication ADD TABLE "SchemaB"."Table2";
etc...
An important point is the Host 2 contains local schema
So my questions are below :
How can i initiate the replication ?
Should I set a pgdump for the schema A & B from Host 1 to Host 2 ?
At which moment should I create the subscription on Host 2 ?
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION subscription_schemaA CONNECTION 'host=X.X.X.X port=ZZZZ password=password user=replica_usr dbname=database' PUBLICATION schemaA_publication;
Which rights needs the user/role on database/schema to prevent access error ?
Thank a lot for your help
